# C# loop through column A and column B for matches

Tags: c#

I have a table with columns ID, MenuText, and ParentID.

I need to take the first value from ID and loop through the values in ParentID for any matches. If there is a match, insert the value from MenuText that is the same row count as column ID into a string. If there is no match, proceed to second value in column ID and loop through the values in column ParentID for matches.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
ID  MenuText    ParentID
1   Vegetable   NULL
2   Fruit       NULL
3   Meat        NULL
4   Lettuce     1
5   Orange      2
6   Sausage     3
```

Here is my code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=GTPerformancelot;Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from List_Cars_Menu", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);


    string link1 = dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
    string text;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        if (string.Compare(dr["ParentID"].ToString(), link1, true) == 0)
            text = (dr["MenuText"].ToString());
    }



}
```

When I debug, I am not returning any values.

Comment: In this case your output should be `Lettuce ,   Orange , Sausage` right?

Comment: Are you getting any records in dt.Rows?

Comment: What is the expected output? `Lettuce`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do simple self Join on `DataTable` using `Linq`

```
var rows = from t1 in table.AsEnumerable()
           join t2 in table.AsEnumerable()
           on t1.Field<string>("ID") equals t2.Field<string>("ParentID")
           select t2.Field<string>("MenuText");
```

**Ouput**

```
Lettuce
Orange
Orange
```

Working [`code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xCHAsO)